# Clearing Buffer in Go

Tags: go

I'm new to Golang and while I'm trying to get consecutive input, The first scanf() gets the input and the remaining scanf() are omitted

Eg:

```
 fmt.Println("Enter A: ")
  fmt.Scanf("%d",a)
  fmt.Println("Enter B: ")
  fmt.Scanf("%d",b)
```

In this, the first Scanf works while the second one doesn't get any input

Comment: Missed a double quote in your original code too?

Answer (score 1):

Use scan instead of scanf since you are trying to take int,

```
    var a, b int    
    fmt.Println("Enter A: ")
    fmt.Scan(&a)
    fmt.Println("Enter B: ")
    fmt.Scan(&b)
```

If you want a string input,

```
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    var a,b string
    fmt.Println("Enter A: ")
    a, _ := reader.ReadString("\n")
    fmt.Println("Enter B: ")
    b, _ := reader.ReadString("\n")
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, i will note that suggestion for String

Answer (score 0):

I think you made a typo:

```
fmt.Println("Enter B: ) 

fmt.Println("Enter B: ")
```

Notice the difference?

Comment: Sorry, I made the error while typing in Question body Its good in my text editor

Comment: @Nivas Please edit your question if you made an error in it to reflect the correct code.